# JIRA rest API max row

Tags: jira, powerbi, powerquery, jira-rest-api, m

I am connecting a JIRA to Power BI so I can make my own reports.

To do this I use the JIRA web API. But the problem is that I am limited to a max row of 1000.

How can I do to retreive all rows into power BI. Should I do some kind of cycle with parameters? Should concatenate n queries in power query, but when comes new rows, how to deal with them.

Any one any idea?
thx

Answer (score 1):

This is not a trivial task. Most REST APIs use pagination and limit the number of results per page. I would advise you to follow [this article on how to do pagination in Power Query](https://medium.com/@marktiedemann/how-to-do-pagination-in-power-query-430460c17c78) written by Mark Tiedemann. I successfully applied the pattern he describes to retrieve tens of thousands of Jira issues in Power BI.

Your idea of concatenation is almost correct. But instead of creating multiple queries (difficult to maintain), a single query is sufficient:
In this query, you retrieve the first page of results which contains the total number of results which you use to calculate the total number of pages. For each page, retrieve all issues (offset and limit). Finally, concatenate all pages into a single list or table.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the Jira Connect application on Power BI.  Just enter the URL for your Jira instance, and it will automatically use the Jira REST API.

Example: `https://my.jira.app:2990` (note: no path to the REST API).

If Power BI doesn't ask for credentials (happens often), then change your credentials in the dataset web credentials (select Basic authentication).